# Required VPN Type

Tags: debian, home-networking, strongswan

So I want to setup a VPN on my Debian server at home using Strongswan w/IPSec using IKEv2 pre-issued certificates using my my own CA.

The way I plan to work it out single tunnel so all traffic is encrypted, sent to my server and done accordingly, the main reason why I want this is to access local network resources (IE. DLNA Server/Samba server) with support of MOBIKE for my iPhone 6s.

The question I have is how would I got about doing this? Setting up a host-host connection? Remote access (If so PSK auth or RSA w/ X.502 certs) Will I require a virtual lan (I do wish to have multiple clients connected at once, but none should be using the same certificate)?